# How to make perfect square shaped image/button

Tags: android, xml, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

I am designing a basic sudoko GAME for android. I want a 4x4 table with all cells as squares in it.

I am trying this with the 16 Buttons in a `TableLayout`.

My way looks like this

- [image]

they are rectange in shape :(

my xml

```
<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/tl"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="@style/box_sky_blue"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="@style/box_sky_blue"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="@style/box_sky_blue"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        style="@style/box_sky_blue"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="4" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        style="@style/box_sky_blue"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        style="@style/box_sky_blue"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        style="@style/box_sky_blue"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        style="@style/box_sky_blue"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="8" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        style="@style/box_sky_blue"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        style="@style/box_sky_blue"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        style="@style/box_sky_blue"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        style="@style/box_sky_blue"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="7" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        style="@style/box_sky_blue"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button14"
        style="@style/box_sky_blue"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button15"
        style="@style/box_sky_blue"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button16"
        style="@style/box_sky_blue"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="7" />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

here is box sky blue

```
<style name="box_sky_blue">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/box_color_sky_blue</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

How to make them sqaure since I have square of 4x4,5x5 & 6x6

Comment: can u post code of box_sky_blue.xml from style

Comment: @Androidiseverythingforme please review :)

Comment: if you are using constraint layout and the height is set to 0 dp then set the width to 0dp and use this app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAbdelkader 4 years back constraint layout was not introduced in sdk it came in 2018

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change the wrap_contents to a default size:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_width="@dimen/box_size"
android:layout_height="@dimen/box_size"
```

(and then set the box_size in the `res/values/dimen.xml` like: `<dimen name="box_size">50dp</dimen>`)

---

OR, use wrap_content for the width, and then in code use `myBox.setHeight(myBox.getMeasuredWidth);` so the width and height match. Just make sure the view is completely loaded though, otherwise getMeasuredWidth returns 0.

EDIT:

To change the height to match the wrap_content width after the View is loaded, you can use a ViewTreeObserver:

```
if(yourActivityLayout.getViewTreeObserver().isAlive()){
    yourActivityLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout(){
            // The view is completely loaded now, so getMeasuredWidth() won't return 0
            yourButton1.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(yourButton1.getMeasuredWidth(), yourButton1.getMeasuredWidth()));
            ... // Do this for all buttons (preferably in a for-loop to prevent repetition)

            // Destroy the onGlobalLayout afterwards, otherwise it keeps changing
            // the sizes non-stop, even though it's already done
            yourActivityLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer, just works:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="1"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Button code in XML

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"  
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"/>
```

buttonshape.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
android:topRightRadius="0dp"
android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>
<solid
android:color="#0000ff"/>
<padding
android:left="0dp"
android:top="0dp"
android:right="0dp"
android:bottom="0dp"/>
<size
android:width="64dp"
android:height="64dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: this is hardcoded. You have to provide a solution that is not hardcoded.

Answer (score -5):

Try to add fixed width and height.

```
 android:layout_width="@dimen/box_size"
 android:layout_height="@dimen/box_size"
```

and in res/values/dimen.xml add

```
 <dimen name="box_size">40dp</dimen>
```