# How do I specify the height of a view relative to its width in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

#### Problem

I have a button with the following XML:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/firstNumber"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/firstNumber"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/secondNumber"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Currently, the button's `layout_width` is set to `match_constraint` (which is the reason why it shows as "0dp," I think).

I want to make the button a square, where its width would be equal to its height. Here are the solutions that I have found so far:

#### Solution 1:

I could do something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24928215/8624603), where I would change the XML `layout_width` and `layout_height` values to a specific value `@dimen/box_size`:

```
android:layout_width="@dimen/box_size"
android:layout_height="@dimen/box_size"
```

However, this would not be ideal as it is basically hard-coding the button width, which would not adjust well for different screen sizes (as opposed to using `match_constraint`).

#### Solution 2:

I could write some Java code to do it ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28846185/8624603)):

```
public class SquareButton extends Button {

    public SquareButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth());
    }
}
```

This would work, but I'd rather do this within XML. Is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below approach and check

> You can also define one dimension of a widget as a ratio of the other one. In order to do that, you need to have at least one constrained dimension be set to 0dp (i.e., MATCH_CONSTRAINT), and set the attribute layout_constraintDimensionRatio to a given ratio.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/firstNumber"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="First Number"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/secondNumber"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

> Please refer below code, for put four square button in horizontal line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/firstNumber"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="FN"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/secondNumber"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/secondNumber"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="SN"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/firstNumber"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/thirdnumber"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/thirdnumber"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TN"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/secondNumber"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/fourtnumber"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fourtnumber"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="FON"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/thirdnumber"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

For more refer the **Ratio** in this [Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout)

**Four dynamic square imageview in horizontal**

[image: Four dynamic square imageview in horizontal]

Comment: It got the ratio right, but for some reason, the width shrunk. Now it isn't really matching the constraint :/.

Comment: @Frank, have you added app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio ??, and can you please post full xml code.

Comment: Yes that is what I added.

Comment: I basically just have 4 buttons that are similar to the one above all in a horizontal chain. The only thing I have added is `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"` on each of the buttons.

Comment: @Frank, i have updated my answer, i have wriiten code for arranging four button in horizontal with square size.

Comment: Just figured out the exact same solution a minute ago. Thanks!

Comment: @Frank, Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Use Square Image in ImageView instead of Button. Use that ImageView instead of Button.

Comment: I just tried it, but the problem is, the `layout_height` is still limiting it from expanding to fill up the `layout_width`. Basically there is a lot of white space on the sides. Also, if there was a way to do this within a button (there has to be right?!), I would prefer that. Thanks for the help anyways! :)

Comment: for white space in imageview, put the attribute adjustViewBouds="true" for that.

Comment: i don't think other way in the button.

Comment: Okay, that worked. Thanks. Still going to see if I can get it done with just a button though (if not I'll accept your answer).